# Common Entity Framework Project "No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider"

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, connection-string

So I looked at entries with the same error, and either it is not the same problem, or I am not understanding it.

I have a solution with several projects.  They use a common `Entity Frame Work 6` and include it in there references.  The `WCF` project works great using the `Entity Frame` to get data from the database. But my console application gives me,

> No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with
>   invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'

when executing the same code calling the `Entity Framework`.

I think I am missing something in the `.config` file, but my connection strings are all the same.

Entity Framework App.Config:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SafetyPortalEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntityModels.SafetyPortalModel.csdl|res://*/EntityModels.SafetyPortalModel.ssdl|res://*/EntityModels.SafetyPortalModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=ndmasdev;initial catalog=SafetyPortal;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

WCF Web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="SafetyPortalEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntityModels.SafetyPortalModel.csdl|res://*/EntityModels.SafetyPortalModel.ssdl|res://*/EntityModels.SafetyPortalModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=ndmasdev;initial catalog=SafetyPortal;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Console App.config:

```
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SafetyPortalEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntityModels.SafetyPortalModel.csdl|res://*/EntityModels.SafetyPortalModel.ssdl|res://*/EntityModels.SafetyPortalModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=ndmasdev;initial catalog=SafetyPortal;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>  
</configuration>
```

Comment: I think the EF app.config is not used at runtime. Have you tried copying the `entityFramework` configuration section to your Console app.config?

Comment: Yes, I tried adding the <configSections> and <entityFramework> parts from the EF App.Config to the Console App.Config and it gives me a error when it tries to initialize an EF object. "The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception."  If I just add the <configSections> it still gives the original error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the package manager console (Tools->Nuget Package Manager->Package manager console) and add entity framework to the Console app using

```
install-package entityframework
```

Be sure to choose the console app in the Default project dropdown in package manager console.

Answer (score 0):

After much frustration I finally figured out what was wrong.

A WCF project automatically includes a reference for Entity Framework in the References so it worked fine.

The Console application did not have a EF reference, but when trying to add a new reference, it doesn't show up in the options list anywhere and including the other project didn't include the EF reference. (I have no idea why)  So I selected "EntityFramework" from the References in the EF project, copied the path for it, and then did a browse add in the Console Project References with the path from the EF project.

There has got to be a better solution for this, if you post it, I will select yours as the answer.